# Using OneToOne cascade with custom child repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following parent entity:

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Address address;
}
```

And the following child entity:

```
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private final String address;
}
```

For child entity I have a custom repository, extending the defult one. Here is the implementation:

```
@Override
    public <S extends Address> S save(S address) {
        //Some important additional logic here, lets say it will be log:
        log.info("The problem is that this message does not appear when I create a user entity!");

        //And perform a simple save operation
        if (entityInformation.isNew(address)) {
            entityManager.persist(address);
            return address;
        } else {
            return entityManager.merge(address);
        }
    }
```

When I create user it cascadly creates a linked address. BUT when it does so, it uses default Save method from default Address repository and not my overriden method. So it misses an important logic for saving address. How can I make it to use the overriden method?

Here is how I create a user:

```
User user = new User();
user.setEmail("test@test.test");
user.setAddress(new Address("My address"));
userRepo.save(user);
```

Comment: try: `public Address save(Address address)` instead of the generic type (a potential reason why the default method is picked up).

Comment: Whay are you using a custom repository when he standard CrudRepository implements exactly the same logic?? Additionally, on a cascading save, no repository method is invoked for the depenedent entity. The insert/update is handled directly by the JPA implementation. What problem are you trying to solve? Ask a question about that rather than your preceived solution:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/276261

Comment: @AlanHay, I just put this custom repository implementation as example. In fact it does additional important logic when saving the child entity.

Comment: The problem is that I need child entities to be handled cascadly when some changes happens to parent entity, but with one thing - the behaviour of save, remove, merge etc should be different from simple JPA implementation.

Comment: As I noted, `save` in the Address repo will not be called on cascading save. You'd need to manually save the address i.e. not via cascade. *in fact it does additional important logic when saving the child entity*. Then why not ask a question about how that can be best achieved? You are asking a question about why your *perceived* solution does not work rather than your *actual* problem.

Comment: *it uses default Save method from default Address repository*. Just to clarify it is not using any `save(address)` method from any repo.

Comment: @AlanHay, thanks for clarifications! Any suggestions how can I achieve my goal the best way? Currently I use a solution with additional custom repository for User, with overriden Save method that in addition saves the child node too (calls Save method from child repo). But I dont really like this. Maybe there is another way?

Comment: As I said edit your question to reflect the problem you want to solve which seems to be about executing some logic on persist.